# Get most searched keywords in WordPress

Tags: search

Normally, visitors of a website search for random keywords. Some keywords searched by many people.

Is it possible to get a list of keywords along with the number of search volumes that are searched by peoples? And filter those keywords by popularity. If it's possible, how can I do that?

Comment: If they're using the WordPress native search, then you can get the search terms with [`get_search_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_query/). You could store them in an option, along with a count of how often each term appears.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. It would be nice if I get the total solution with code examples.

Comment: The main idea of this site is to help people fix or improve their code, not provide entire solutions - read more about the subject and share some basics functions - then people can help with the details.